# How can i fix the libsodium error in java project

Tags: java, libsodium

this exception appear when i create a new instance of SigningKey from libsodium, how have any idea to solve this problem?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sodiumjni in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.libsodium.jni.NaCl.<clinit>(NaCl.java:29)
    at org.libsodium.jni.keys.SigningKey.<init>(SigningKey.java:41)
    at tech.digitus.carthage.kanouni.utils.SecretKey.<init>(SecretKey.java:28)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its clearly saying that sodiumjni dependency is not in the classpath. Try to add it to the classpath and try again.

Try below command

```
java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/dependency/directory
```